# Make a class inherit from another and at same time generalise it

Tags: c#, generics

I need to make class which is inheriting from class say A.

```
public class B: A
{
 ........
}
```

but also I want to create it as generic like

```
public class B<T> where T: class : A
{
   public T Data {get;set;}
   .......
}
```

How can I define such a class?

Comment: `public class B<T> : A` ?

Comment: `public class B<T> : A where T : A`? I'm not sure what you're after, or why you're asking for this. Why interit _and_ also require it as a generic argument?

Comment: Assuming you're not trying to constrain `T` to be an `A`: `public class B<T> : A where T : class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the generic type condition with the class you want to derive as below.

- If you want to constraint T, you can do this afterward.

```cs
public class B<T> : A
   where T: class
{
   public T Data {get;set;}
   .......
}
```

Comment: Side note: I doubt if `where T: class` required here (why `T` *must* be reference type and must not be a `struct`)

Comment: Yes, probably it's not required. But maybe she wants to be sure about T is a class. That's why I did not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess*, you are after something like this:

```
public class B : A  {
  ...
}
```

And then `B<T>` is the *same* as generalized `B` but with generic:

```
public class B<T> : B  {
  public T Data {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

Note, that since `B` inherits from `A`, `B<T>` inherits from `A` as well. I *doubt* if you insist on `T` being `class` (i.e. reference type) while `struct`s (e.g. `int`, `double`, `bool`) are forbidden. If, however, you want to impose such a restriction, put it as

```
public class B<T> : B where T : class {
  public T Data {get; set;}
  ...
}
```